# Dynamically Resize iFrame which has dynamic content with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iFrame loaded like this:

```
<iframe src="http://otherdomain.com/sourceContent.html" id="theIframe" frameborder="0" seamless>
```

I need to resize it dynamically so there are never any scrollbars, the content inside can get taller vertically (dynamically based on what the user clicks on).

I know you can resize the iframe dynamically on page load, but what about if the contents of the iFrame grow?

Also the source HTML is on a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your  section

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

And change your iframe to this:

```
<iframe src="http://otherdomain.com/sourceContent.html" id="theIframe"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about sizing it dynamically based on something that might change in the iframe after load this can be tricky. If the iframe is controlled by you or is from the same domain it will be easier, otherwise it might not be consistently possible depending on the browser and site being loaded.

iframes create security sandboxes of sorts so that the pages cannot communicate one with another except through [Post Message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) (or if they are from the same domain, it can be possible through plain javascript.)

Some code inside the frame would need to message to the outer window and it would have to be resized that way. If you control both then you only need JavaScript similar to the kind posted in @Sujit 's answer